# How do I display a static list with added items from a csv file on MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

Category Controller:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private static List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

    static int counter = 0;

    // GET: Category
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(string Cname)
    {
        categoryList.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = Cname, CategoryId = counter });

        var categories = categoryList;

        using (StreamWriter CA = new StreamWriter(path: "C:\\Users\\Claudio Gopie\\3D Objects\\ToDoList\\Category.csv"))
        {
            foreach (var category in categories)
            {
                CA.WriteLine((category.CategoryName, category.CategoryId));
            }
        }

        @ViewBag.Msg = "Category Added: " + Cname + "," + counter;

        counter++;

        return View(categoryList);
    }
```

Category Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

List View:

```
<table class="table">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @item.CategoryName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a list in table view from a list that I am adding to. In this assignment I am required to create a simple To Do List using MVC and text documents to store the details of my list.
There should be a button to submit the form and a back button that will always redirect the user to the
Index page.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should write code that displays the list in an "Index" function. You can then just return "Index()" from your Add functions. Your Razor view seems to be lacking @model at the top which would help with intellisense - also, if you just want to output HTML, all you need is @(item.CategoryName) - the brackets might not be required. You'll also need to LOAD the list at some point.

Comment: How exactly do you load a list?

Comment: There are a number of ways to load a list in the .Net Class Library. The simplest way to load data from a text file is to use System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename)